# Java Repeat a check x times with changed variables

Tags: java, repeat

I have this little piece of code for a world generation process and I want to have something very simple to make the creation easy to expand in size.

So I have this terrain which is generated several times in a row on the x axis, and what I want is, that when a certain amount of terrains have been placed it should move upwards. This is my current code:

```
if(terrain == 5) { alpha = alpha+ 1; origin = -distance; }
```

Which means if I wanted to have it jump every fith time I would need to have several of these if statements and cover all possible numbers:

```
if(terrain == 5) { alpha = alpha+ 1; origin = -distance; }
if(terrain == 10) { alpha = alpha+ 1; origin = -distance; }
if(terrain == 15) { alpha = alpha+ 1; origin = -distance; }
if(terrain == 20) { alpha = alpha+ 1; origin = -distance; }
```

and so on..

Now It would be much better if I could do that in one go and tell the program somehow that it should do it every x-th time without having to tell it seperately.

Here's the entire while loop that handles the generation:

```
    float alpha         = 0;
    float terrain       = 0;
    float origin        = 0;
    float distance      = 45;
    float num           = 20;

        while(terrain < num) {
            if(terrain == 0) {
                create_terrain(0,0,distance*alpha); terrain ++;
            }
                create_terrain(origin+distance,0,distance*alpha);
            terrain ++;
            origin += distance;

            if(terrain == 5) { alpha = alpha+ 1; origin = -distance; }
            if(terrain == 10) { alpha = alpha+ 1; origin = -distance; }
            if(terrain == 15) { alpha = alpha+ 1; origin = -distance; }
        }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator:

```
if((terrain % 5) == 0) { alpha = alpha+ 1; origin = -distance; }
```

The condition is true if terrain is a multiple of 5.
If there is a max value, add a `&& terrain < something`

Comment: 11 Seconds before me! +1

Comment: Huh? This obviously does not the same thing as the given code, since it only executes the statement once instead of ceil(n / 5) times.

Comment: @Voo Yeah, it only executes the content once, *like the original if chain too*. Only one of the if's can be entered.

Answer (score 2):

Modulus operator can work for you here!

```
if(terrain % 5 == 0) {
     // Do your stuff.
}
```

**How This Works**

Modulo is a mathematical operation. It takes the remainder of an integer division. For example, 20 modulo 5 is 0, because 5 fits into 20 four times with no remainder. 21 modulo 5 is 1, because 5 fits into 20 four times with one remained.

The useful thing is, you can check if a value is a multiple of another value, by ensuring that the result of the modulus operation is 0, since it means that the value "fits into" the other value with no remainder.

**Extra Reading**

- The Modulus operator is well known in Java. You can read about it [here](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html)